# Trading out 110W processor for 35W processor: how much could I really save?

Tags: cpu, energy-saving

My current processor is a 110W AMD X2 4600+.  For fun, I was looking at a 35W Core i3 2100T.  Looking around I couldn't find a direct performance comparison anywhere between the two, but it looks like the i3 would actually bring a (very) small performance bump vs the 4600+.  The upgrade would also involve a move from 2GB DD2 to 8GB DDR3, so as long as I don't lose too much this will be a win, performance-wise.  The price (cpu,mb,and ram) would come to about $310.

I really don't have any budget for upgrades right now, but I was curious: if I were to go ahead and get this, how long would it take for the energy savings to pay for the upgrade?  Could I justify the purchase this year on energy savings alone?

I suspect not, and I know it depends on usage and local rates.  But I'm hoping to be able to put a ballpark figure together for how much I could save in a year.  As a reference, local rates are $.0933/kWhr

I'll start with a basic calculation that uses a few bad assumptions, and we'll see if we can refine it any:

Assuming both systems are running full-capacity, that means I save 75W/hr.  I also have to dissipate that energy, so I really save 150W/hr, or .15kWhrs.  .15 * .0933 = $.013995 save per hour I run the new system.  .013995 * 24hrs/day * 7days/wk * 52wks/year results in $122.26 saved per year. So I'd need to run this for about 2 1/2 years to pay back the investment.  And again, that's assuming 100% run all the time and an additional 100% cost for heat, neither of which are very good.  Can we get even more accurate numbers?

Comment: get yourself a kill-a-watt and actually make these measurements. http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=kill+a+watt&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=5525303247386121198&sa=X&ei=gij1TeyvMseutwf81JyDBw&ved=0CFYQ8wIwAg

Comment: I made interesting discoveries, my window fan on high uses more power than my AC on high fan and the AC moves more air than the window fan.

Comment: You'll spend more for heating your house :)

Comment: Do you live in the tropics and never have cool or cold days?  Otherwise you are inflating your energy cost by adding "100% cost for heat".

Comment: I'm not sure if there are any more accurate ways.

Comment: Figure out the idle power for both systems, that should give you a rough estimate of a more realistic situation. Second - do you care about noise? The 35W CPU is likely to be quieter.

Comment: The presumption of maximal consumption is also a major source for error.  Even for estimation purposes, Joel, you should buy an inexpensive load meter and use it on your existing system for a week.  If the meter doesn't have a loggin function (most cheap ones don't) just keep a manual log at regular intervals.  Then use your current loading information to make projections.  There will still be a high degree of error, but less than your stated estimates.  Only impute for heating during the months you use A/C.